# Pandas iterrows too slow, how can I vectorize this code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, swifter

I'm a Jr. Data Scientist and I'm trying to solve a problem that may be simple for experienced programmers. I'm dealing with Big Data on GCP and I need to optimize my code.

```
                                      [...]
    def send_to_bq(self, df):
        result = []
        for i, row in df[["id", "vectors", "processing_timestamp"]].iterrows():
            data_dict = {
                "processing_timestamp": str(row["processing_timestamp"]),
                "id": row["id"],
                "embeddings_vector": [str(x) for x in row["vectors"]],
            }
            result.append(data_dict)
                                      [...]
```

Our DataFrame have the following pattern:

```
           id                                               name  \
0  3498001704  roupa natal flanela animais estimacao traje ma...   

                                             vectors  \
0  [0.4021441, 0.45425776, 0.3963987, 0.23765437,...   

        processing_timestamp  
0 2021-10-26 23:48:57.315275
```

Using iterrows on a DataFrame is too slow. I've been studying alternatives and I know that:

1. I can use apply
2. I can vectorize it through Pandas Series (better than apply)
3. I can vectorize it through Numpy (better that Pandas vectorization)
4. I can use Swifter - which uses apply method and then decides the better solution for you between Dask, Ray and vectorization

But I don't know how I can transform my code for those solutions.

Can anyone help me demonstrating a solution for my code? One is enough, but if someone could show more than one solution would be really educational for this matter.

Any help I will be more than grateful!

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df.head().to_string(index=False))` as a reproducible sample

Comment: Use `df.to_dict(['processing_timestamp', 'id', 'embeddings_vector'])`

Comment: Thank you for the amendment. Best practices are to make my code reproducible on Stack Overflow, you're right. I will print the head and edit my Question.

Comment: I've edited my Question and incorporated the head from the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically convert everything to string and then transform your DataFrame to a list of dict

For the second part, there is a pandas method `to_dict`. For the first part, I would use `astype` and `apply` only to convert the type

```
df["processing_timestamp"] = df["processing_timestamp"].astype(str)
df["embeddings_vector"] = df["vectors"].apply(lambda row: [str(x) for x in row])
result = df[["id", "embeddings_vector", "processing_timestamp"]].to_dict('records')
```

A bit hard to test without sample data but hopefully this helps ;) Also, like I did with the `lambda` function you could basdically wrap your entire loop body inside an `apply`, but that would create far to many temporary dicitionaries to be fast.

Comment: It worked perfectly. You understood correctly although I didn't post a data sample (I need to anonymize it first).  I needed to transform everything to string and this is the better solution, using astype for timestamp, apply with lambda function for a list of vectors (actually an array) and using to_dict with 'records' so it can iterate similarly to iterrows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agg`:

```
>>> df.agg({'id': str, 'vectors': lambda v: [str(i) for i in v], 
            'processing_timestamp': str}).to_dict('records')

[{'id': '3498001704',
  'vectors': ['0.4021441', '0.45425776', '0.3963987', '0.23765437'],
  'processing_timestamp': '2021-10-26 23:48:57.315275'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame` methods to convert it to other types such as `DataFrame.to_dict()` and [more](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).